# Return a non iterator from __iter__

Tags: python

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        return "my string"

o = test()
print iter(o)
```

Why does this give a traceback ?

```
$ python iter_implement.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iter_implement.py", line 9, in <module>
    print iter(o)
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'str'
```

I was hoping `__iter__` to just return the string in this case. When and why is it detected that the returned object is not an iterator object ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code can be repaired by adding an *iter()* call:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter("my string")
```

Here is a sample run:

```
>>> o = test()
>>> iter(o)
<iterator object at 0x106bfa490>
>>> list(o)
['m', 'y', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

The reason for the original error is that the API for *__iter__* purports to return an actual iterator.  The *iter()* function checks to make sure the contract is fulfilled.

Note, this kind of error checking occurs in other places as well.  For example, the *len()* function checks to make sure a *__len__()* method returns an integer:

```
>>> class A:
        def __len__(self):
            return 'hello'

>>> len(A())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    len(A())
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: _The iter() function checks to make sure the contract is fulfilled._ ... not very thoroughly, though ;-) Well, probably good enough to catch the odd foot shot.

Answer (score 8):

`str` is an *iterable* but not an *iterator*, subtle but important difference. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/62138) for an explanation.

You want to return an object with `__next__` (or just `next` if py2) which is what `str` returns when is iterated.

```
def __iter__(self):
      return iter("my string")
```

`str` does not implement `__next__`

```
In [139]: s = 'mystring'

In [140]: next(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-bc0566bea448> in <module>()
----> 1 next(s)

TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

However calling iter returns the iterator, which is what looping calls:

```
In [141]: next(iter(s))
Out[141]: 'm'
```

You get the same problem returning anything without a `__next__` (or `next` in py2) method

You can use a generator, which itself has `__iter__` that returns `self`:

```
def gen():
    yield 'foo'

gg = gen()

gg is gg.__iter__()
True

gg.__next__()
'foo'

class Something:
     def __iter__(self):
         return gen()

list(Something())
['foo']
```

Or a class where you implement `__next__` yourself, like this class similar to the one on the Ops post (you also have to handle `StopIteration` which stops the loop)

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, somestring):
        self.s = iter(somestring)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.s) ## this exhausts the generator and raises StopIteration when done.

In [3]: s = test('foo')

In [4]: for i in s:
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:
f
o
o
```

Comment: Question is not how to fix the code. The question is why the error? I know the difference between iterable and iterator.

Comment: @abc apologies that you knew the difference, but pointing it out will surely benefit other people. Also, added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `__iter__` magic function is to return something that you can iterate (e.g. loop) through. The most common solution is to return `iter(something)` where `something` could be a list, a tuple, set, dictionary, a string... anything that we can iterate through. Take a look at this example:

```
class Band:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []

    def add_member(self, name):
        self.members.append(name)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.members)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    band = Band()
    band.add_member('Peter')
    band.add_member('Paul')
    band.add_member('Mary')

    # Magic of __iter__:
    for member in band:
        print(member)
```

Output:

```
Peter
Paul
Mary
```

In this case, the `__iter__` magic function allows us to loop through `band` as if it is a collection of members. That means in your case, return "my string" will not do. If you want a list of chars in "my string":

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter("my string")  # ==> m, y, ' ', s, t, r, i, n, g
```

However, if you want to return a list with a single element "my string", then:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(["my string"])
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question. Python2 appears to check for the presence of a `.next` class attribute:

```
>>> class test(object):
...     next = None
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return self
... 
>>> print iter(test())
<__main__.test object at 0x7fcef75c2f50>
```

An instance attribute won't do:

```
>>> class test(object):
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.next = None
...    def __iter__(self):
...        return self
... 
>>> print iter(test())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'test'
```

Comment: Intersting and you answered my actual question along with Raymond Hettinger.