# Confused about __iter__(self) and iter()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class like this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = [1,2,3]
```

Now I want to iterate over the `test` property like this:

```
a = MyClass()
for i in a:
    print(I)
```

So I've added another method to the class:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self.test
```

Which doesn't work, unless I instead do this:

```
return iter(self.test)
```

I thought the `for` loop implicitly calls `iter()` behind the scenes and it's obviously capable of iterating over a normal list if I would do `for i in a.test` so obviously I'm not understanding something about using those functions. Would love some clarification

Comment: @jonrsharpe Anything wrong with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124461/return-a-non-iterator-from-iter) as a dupe target? (You reopened after I added that question to the list; not sure if you noticed it)

Comment: A list is *iterable* but it's not an *iterator*, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9884132/3001761

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think that about covers it, sure; I misread with the first one I suggested, didn't realised you'd added to the list, sorry!

Comment: I don't see the answer I'm looking for in that question and answer, I'm looking for an explanation of the different uses of `iter` and `__iter__()`

Comment: Not sure what your question is, then. The obvious difference between the two is that one is a function and the other is a method, so you can't do `__iter__('abc')` or `def iter(self):`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe doesn't the `list` have a `__next__` implemented?

Comment: @OferSadan No, it doesn't. Lists are **iterables**, not **iterators**.

Comment: I understand now thank you, apologies for the confusion

Comment: The third question added as duplicate now really answered my question